# range.selectNodeContents is this undefined in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, range

I'm trying to select the text inside a `<p>` element, but why is     `selectNodeContents` undefined in chrome? Below is my implementation:

```
range = document.createRange();
var sel = window.getSelection();
range.selectNodeContents(el);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of `selectNodeContents()`, the word "select" has nothing to do with the user selection. Instead, it means that the range boundaries move to encompass the element's contents. In fact, all range methods apply only to the range and don't generally affect the selection.

What I assume you want is

```
var range = document.createRange();
var sel = window.getSelection();
range.selectNodeContents(el);
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
```